# Using iptables inside an unprivileged (rootless/fakeroot) network namespace results in permission error with `/run/xtables.lock`

Tags: linux, networking, permissions, mount, iptables

I'm using `unshare` to create an unprivileged network namespace:

```
unshare -Unr
```

This gives us a network namespace that should be capable of using iptables.

However upon running it:

```
iptables -L
```

We get:

```
Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied
```

This is because iptables uses the `/run/xtables.lock` for concurrency control, and this needs to be isolated from the host-namespace and potentially other network namespaces. To do this, it appears I need a mount namespace.

```
unshare -Umnr
touch /tmp/randomfile
mount --bind /tmp/randomfile /run/xtables.lock
iptables -L
```

Now it works.

However we are not guaranteed that the `/run/xtables.lock` file exists. It may not exist upon booting up. In such a case the `mount --bind` call will fail because the target mount point doesn't exist. Within the namespace I also cannot just create `/run/xtables.lock` because I don't have root permissions to create files in `/run`.

What's the solution to this? I cannot just mount over the entire `/run` because it has important binaries and configuration we need from the host namespace. I also tried using an overlayfs on the `/run`, but I'm hitting permission issues there on attempting to mount over `/run`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a "host" file as the lock file in the first place?

Comment: I'm not "trying" to do this. This is builtin to the iptables program source.

Comment: If you switch to `iptables-nft` rather than `iptables-legacy` then use of a lock file is not needed anymore (and also the `-w` option which is the actual user of this lock file becomes a no-op) since the *nftables* backend automatically grants atomic transactions to the *iptables* front end. So why are you still using the legacy version of iptables?